# Keep selected treenodes after filtering

Tags: c#, treeview

Keep selected treenodes after filtering the treeview
I filter a treeview. when there are checked nodes i want to keep the checked nodes in the filtered treeview. And when i remove the filter the nodes must still be checked.
I am doing something wrong , the filter works but i loose the checkes.

```
List<string> ListCheckboxItems = new List<string>(); //create a list from the checkedlistbox itmes
List<string> KeepSelectedItems = new List<string>(); //Create a list with the selected items


        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  //new 24-12-2017
        {
            var filteredItems = ListCheckboxItems.Where(item => item.Contains(textBox1.Text));

            List<string> FilterList = filteredItems.ToList();


            treeViewFilter.Nodes.Clear();           //remove all nodes
            foreach (object item in FilterList)     //Fill it again with only the filtered items
            {
                treeViewFilter.Nodes.Add(item.ToString());  //new 24-12-2017
            }

            foreach (string keepitem in KeepSelectedItems)  //Keep the items checked when filter starts
            {
                TreeNode[] arr = treeViewFilter.Nodes.Find(keepitem, true);

                foreach (TreeNode s in arr)
                {
                    treeViewFilter.SelectedNode = s;
                    s.Checked = true;
                }
            }

            //check if empty the put the original list back
            if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)  //park the checked items
            {
                foreach (string item in KeepSelectedItems)
                {
                    TreeNode[] arr = treeViewFilter.Nodes.Find(item, true);
                    foreach (TreeNode s in arr)
                    {
                        treeViewFilter.SelectedNode = s;
                        s.Checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it. :

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  //new 24-12-2017
        {
            var filteredItems = ListTreeViewItems.Where(item => item.Contains(textBox1.Text));

            List<string> FilterList = filteredItems.ToList();


            treeViewFilter.Nodes.Clear();           //remove all nodes
            foreach (object item in FilterList)     //Fill it again with only the filtered items
            {
                TreeNode aNode = new TreeNode(item.ToString()) { Name = item.ToString() };  //THIS LINE IS THE SOLUTION
                treeViewFilter.Nodes.Add(aNode);  
            }

            //zet de vinkjes weer terug
            foreach (string keepitem in KeepSelectedItems)  //Keep the items checked when filter starts
            {


                TreeNode[] arr = treeViewFilter.Nodes.Find(keepitem, true);

                Logging.WriteToLog("", "treeViewFilter.Nodes.Find(keepitem, true); " + treeViewFilter.Nodes.Find(keepitem, true));
               // Logging.WriteToLog("", "test " + test);

                foreach (TreeNode s in arr)
                {
                    treeViewFilter.SelectedNode = s;
                    s.Checked = true;
                }
            }

            //check if empty the put the original list back
            if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)  //park the checked items
            {
                foreach (string item in KeepSelectedItems)
                {
                    TreeNode[] arr = treeViewFilter.Nodes.Find(item, true);
                    foreach (TreeNode s in arr)
                    {
                        treeViewFilter.SelectedNode = s;
                        s.Checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```